# how tcp communicate for HTTP 1.1

Tags: sockets, tcp, http-1.1

I am exploring `HTTP 1.1` persistent connection over single `TCP` socket for multiple `HTTP` request from client side. One thing I observed in wireshark is that, after each request-response my client sends an `ACK` to server. Is this `ACK` message call right according to protocol standard? Is there any way I can skip this `ACK` call. I compared the communication behaviour of my client with browser's communication pattern. I think browser does not  send any tcp messages to server once tcp handshake is completed to establish connection.

Comment: _" I think browser does not send any tcp messages to server once tcp handshake is completed to establish connection"_ - I think you're wrong. When HTTP runs on top of TCP (which it usually does), you can't send HTTP messages without TCP traffic.

Comment: Why on earth would you want to get rid of an ACK?

Answer (score 3):

`ACK` is part of TCP. You can't have a TCP connection without `ACK`, that's how it works. Data that is received is ACK'ed so the sender does not retransmit it.

`HTTP` is not dependent on `TCP`, you could implement HTTP on other protocols. The two protocols should be seen as separate layers, and should not influence each others.